# How do I stop apps from loading at startup if CMD-OPT-Q doesn't work?

Tags: macos, login-items

The apps are Safari and Xcode, both are loading local files. I close both with the keyboard shortcut in the title but they always launch again at the next startup. My system is running Sierra

Comment: Do you mean, when you start up Xcode and Safari, those files open, or when you start up your computer, Xcode and Safari open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Command-Option-Q" shortcut says in the menu "Quit and Keep Windows". This will remember the windows (files) that are open when you quit, and restore them when you open the application the next time.

If you don't like this behaviour use "Command-Q"

If the problem is when starting up the computer and these applications are started automatically, they are probably in you Login-Items.

See System Preferences > Users & Groups > Your account > Login items and uncheck or remove the applications.

Comment: This is a toggle — depending on how you have "Close windows when quitting an app" set in System Preferences > General, the function of ⌘Q and ⌥⌘Q are reversed.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. I'm used to the old behaviour (like in System 7 days) when there was no toggle, and only 1 way to quit. Whenever this behaviour was introduced, I set it to the familiar way and never looked back.